# Bash script for defining flags depending on current git branch

Tags: xcode, git, ios, bash, scripting

Recently I've encountered a problem. I have an app that talks to the server. I want it to talk to different servers depending on what branch I'm on right now. I think the way for doing that is create a bash script which creates a .h file like

```
#define BRANCH @"{here goes branch name}"
```

The only thing is that I don't know Bash. At all :(

Here is what I've tried

```
branch= git branch| grep '*'
echo $branch
```

Dunno what to do next... (By the way I'm using Xcode and running this in a "Runs script phase")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates the file for the current branch:

```
current_branch=$(git branch --no-color | grep '*' | sed 's/^\*.//')
echo "#define BRANCH @\"$current_branch\"" > file.h
```

file.h would contain: `#define BRANCH @"your current branch"`

Comment: The output is #define BRANCH @development How do you escape quotes in bash?

Comment: Edited to answer your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current Git branch with:

```
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vcprompt

It supports Git, Mercurial, subversion and others(?)

Here is one repo: https://github.com/xvzf/vcprompt#readme

It links to other sources as well